# Map new array based on object's nested attributes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I feel like this has been asked a thousand times, but for the life of me I can't figure it out and the objects are somewhat complicated.

I'm building a photography portfolio site where galleries contain images. I have a response from a Wordpress API coming in that looks like this (simplified):

```
[                                                                                                                                             
  {
    id: 20,
    date: '2020-05-25T20:39:28',
    slug: 'test-image',
    status: 'inherit',
    type: 'attachment',
    author: 1,
    media_category: [
      9
    ],
    acf: {
      location: 'North Carolina',
      category: {
        term_id: 9,
        name: 'North Carolina',
        slug: 'north-carolina',
        term_group: 0,
        term_taxonomy_id: 9,
        taxonomy: 'media_category',
        description: '',
        parent: 0,
        count: 1,
        filter: 'raw'
      }
    },
    ... other details
  },
  ... other objects
]
```

These are just the raw media objects from the Wordpress media endpoint. What I'm trying to do though, is group them together by category slug (acf.category.slug), so I figure I can have an outer array that I can map over for later use, which then contains arrays (galleries), and each of those arrays contain the media objects. Something like:

```
[
  [               <-- Gallery 1
    { Image 1 },
    { Image 2 },
  ],
  [               <-- Gallery 2
    { Image 3 },
    { Image 4 },
  ],
  [               <-- Gallery 3
    { Image 5 },
    { Image 6 },
  ]
]
```

I hope that makes sense.

EDIT:
I wanted to include where I was headed initially with a `.reduce` function:

```
let res = await this.$axios.$get(`${process.env.WP_API_URL}/wp/v2/media`);
const data = res.reduce((images, item) => {
  const image = (images[item.acf.category.term_taxonomy_id]);
  image.push(item);
  images[item.acf.category.slug] = image;
  return images;
}, []);
```

As of now, I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Comment: And the problem is? Grab one of those _"group array of objects by property"_ dupes and just use `acf.category.slug`

Comment: Tip: use `reduce()` or if that's too difficult, a quite simple loop will do too.

Comment: I edited my post with the `.reduce` function that I was attempting.

Comment: `const image = (images[item.acf.category.term_taxonomy_id]);` can be `const image = images[item.acf.category.slug] || [];`

Comment: Why `term_taxonomy_id` when you want to group by `slug`? `images` should be an object and `images[item.acf.slug]` an array of "images".

Comment: @Andreas you're right, I should be grouping by slug. I'm now returning an object with 4 arrays inside (which is correct). Ideally there wouldn't be an outer object wrapper, but I'll figure that part out. Thanks for everybody's help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
let res = await this.$axios.$get(`${process.env.WP_API_URL}/wp/v2/media`);

const data = res.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const {slug} = item.acf.category;
  (acc[slug] || (acc[slug]=[])).push(item)
  return acc
}, {});
```

It generates a structure like:

```js
{
  "north-carolina": [                                                                                                                             
    {
      id: 20,
      date: '2020-05-25T20:39:28',
      slug: 'test-image',
      status: 'inherit',
      type: 'attachment',
      author: 1,
      media_category: [
        9
      ],
      acf: {
        location: 'North Carolina',
        category: {
          term_id: 9,
          name: 'North Carolina',
          slug: 'north-carolina',
          term_group: 0,
          term_taxonomy_id: 9,
          taxonomy: 'media_category',
          description: '',
          parent: 0,
          count: 1,
          filter: 'raw'
        }
      },
      //... other details
    },
    //... other objects
  ],
  //... objects with different slugs
}
```

[Try it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/XWXrEMZ?editors=1111)

Comment: I got a couple of errors: first, `slug is a constant`. So I changed that to `const image = item.acf.category.slug`, then removed the `|| acc[slug]=[]`, but I'm getting `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

Comment: @J.Jackson What's the problem with *my code*? First of all, `|| acc[slug]=[]` is important to create the new property when a new *slug* is found, removing it will really lead to `Cannot read property "push" of undefined`. And, all `const`ants are scoped to their enclosing block (in this case, the callback), so it will be regenerated safely in every iteration (Btw, you might rename the constant to `image`, but then you'll have to change it all the places where the code accesses it). Just try my code *without modifications*, and see if it works...

Comment: After copying and pasting your code to make sure I got it _just_ right, I receive two eslint errors on the line under where you're setting the `const`. The first occurs in the first half of the || statement: `Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression`. The second occurs in the second half of the || statement: `',' expected`. Both cause my app to crash because eslint expects these errors to be resolved.

Comment: @J.Jackson Oh, yes! You're right. That's because of a missing semicolon. I added it, try it now

Comment: Unfortunately I still seem to be receiving the same error.

Comment: I couldn't test it, just answered quickly. Now I manged to work (a pair of parentheses were missing), and tested it, so **it really works now** (see linked Pen). (I'm sorry for my failed attempts)

Comment: Awesome, that works! It's a little sleeker than what I had as well. Thank you!